# swing.Timer does not stop

Tags: java, swing, timer

I use swing.Timer in all my classes , and I got same problem in the all timers
 the problem is : all my timers work good for first time , but in second time all timers they are not stop

this the code for all my timers

```
   Timer timer1;
   S= 0 ;
   ActionListener taskPerformer2 ; = new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                  
        if (  S == 10 ){            
           // My work   
           timer1.stop(); 
        }       
        S++;
        System.out.println(S + "A");
    }; 
 };
 timer1 = new Timer(20, taskPerformer2);
 timer1.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the current timer from the event directly.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                  
  if (  S == 10 ){            
       // My work   
       ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop(); // <-- this was changed
    }       
    S++;
    System.out.println(S + "A");
  };
```

Comment: I'll add this as a side recommendation for OP: Follow [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) i.e. variable names should start with lower case letters while classes names should start with an upper case. This will make your code more readable for you and others :)

Comment: ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop(); ... I did it it not work ...... its work just for first time .... same prblem